# Prevent view from goes up with soft keyboard with adjust resize

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have main activity as container for my fragments with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. My layout contains bottom buttons which goes up with soft keyboard and it's acceptable for most fragments logic. But in one fragment I want to prevent this behavior for bottom buttons. How to achieve that without changing android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"?   I I have layout with such structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/widget_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/container_company_header"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_55dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/container_company_header"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_service_review"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/container_bottom_buttons"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container_company_header"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_review_linear" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/container_bottom_buttons"
        layout="@layout/container_bottom_buttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If the buttons are fixed to the bottom of the `RelativeLayout`, and your activity is resized due to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, then your buttons will be pushed up by the soft keyboard. One of these two things must change if you don't want the buttons to move.

Comment: Can I set adjustResize programmatically for this fragment lifecycle only?

Comment: getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);